# Converting birthday in format DDMMMYY to date value in PHP

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I've got bunch of birthdays which are stored in format DDMMMYY. I need to convert those to date values, so i can store those in database.

Is there any easy way of telling strtotime function that date must be in the past?

```
<?php
$datestring = '22SEP41';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($datestring)); //outputs 2041-09-22, should be 1941-09-22
?>
```

Comment: What year would you expect from a date of `$datestring = '22SEP15';`? 1915 or 2015? Read the last 2 characters of your string, and if it's after a particular cut-off, then modify it by adding `19` or `20` as appropriate

Comment: If the year is specified in a two-digit format, values between 0-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and values between 70-100 are mapped to 1970-2000. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$datestring = '22SEP41';

$matches = [];
preg_match('/([0-9]{2})([A-Z]{3})([0-9]{2})/', $datestring, $matches);

$prefix = ($matches[3] <= date('y') ? '20' : '19');

$matches[3] = "{$prefix}{$matches[3]}";

$ts = strtotime("{$matches[1]} {$matches[2]} {$matches[3]}");

// date ('Y-m-d', $ts) == 1941-09-22
```

This assumes that 22SEP06 should be interpreted as 2006 rather than 1906 - basically it gives the output a range of 1917 -> 2016.

Answer (score 1):

This method create a date of past century only if standard evaluated date is after today:

```
$date = date_create( $datestring );
if( $date->diff( date_create() )->invert )
{
    $date->modify( '-100 years' );
}
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
```

For

```
$datestring = '22SEP41';
```

the output is:

```
1941-09-22
```

For

```
$datestring = '22SEP01';
```

the output is:

```
2001-09-22
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/552188)**</kbd>

Basically, we create a DateTime based on given string, then we calculate difference with current day; if the difference is negative (`->invert`), we subtract 1 century from the date.

You can personalize the condition using `->format('%R%Y')` instead of `->invert`. In this example:

```
if( $date->diff( date_create() )->format('%R%Y') < 10 )
```

Dates from `00` through `05` as evaluated as `2000-2005`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$ds = '22SEP41';

$day = $ds[0].$ds[1];

// Getting the month.
$mon = array(
  'JAN' => 1,
  'FEB' => 2,
  'MAR' => 3,
  'APR' => 4,
  'MAY' => 5,
  'JUN' => 6,
  'JUL' => 7,
  'AUG' => 8,
  'SEP' => 9,
  'OCT' => 10,
  'NOV' => 11,
  'DEC' => 12
);

$mont = $ds[2].$ds[3].$ds[4];
$month = $mon[$mont]; // Gets the month real.

$year = '19'.$ds[5].$ds[6];

$final = $day.'-'.$month.'-'.$year;
```

I tested it on my local machine and it worked. Hope it works and is what you're looking for :)