# Laravel use special date format

Tags: php, laravel, strtotime, php-carbon

Right now i use the `strtotime` function to convert german date format (01.01.2017) to the stock (2017-01-01). For example i use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($birthday))`. Now i want to use the short german date format and convert it to stock. E.g. 1.1.17 should be converted to 2017-01-01. How can i do this? Using the `strtotime` function doesn't work (or I am to silly to use it right)

And another question: How can i catch the error if somebody types in 32.01.2017? I only get a debug notification or, on production, a "Whoops, ..." "error" messsage. Would be great to make some sweet alert message instead. I get following error message:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (32.10.2016) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character

Comment: do you use `protected $dates = [$birthday];` in your model?

Comment: How can i manage it, that i don't get a server error when somebody types in '32.01.2017' and instead catch this case in my controller?

Comment: No, i use `protected $guarded = [];`

Comment: why don't u try using protected $dates?

Comment: because the problem is in carbon and not in my model? Other formats do work,..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one.

```
$date = '1.1.17';
$year = substr($date, -2);
$finalDate= substr($date, 0, -2)."20".$year;
Carbon::createFromFormat('m.d.Y',$finalDate)->format('Y-m-d');
```

(updated).

Comment: but i want to do this thing: `Carbon::parse('1.1.17');` and this does not work ;)

Comment: I try that one using this code
"Carbon::parse('1.1.17')->format('Y-m-d');"  

it works on me bro.

Comment: no dude, doesn't work on me. 1.1.2017 works but 1.1.17 not. Doesn't matter if i use format or not.

Comment: It works on me. I don't know why it not works on you. I think you have other problem encountered.

Comment: Well.. What did you do to make it work? If I do `$birthday = Carbon::parse('1.1.17')->format(Y-m-d); dd($birthday);` I always get todays date

Comment: I update my answer bro, Look and try that one. it works. I wish it will help you

Comment: thanks.. Of course this works.. I already found another (better) solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572264/converting-birthday-in-format-ddmmmyy-to-date-value-in-php?rq=1). But i hoped that there would be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For manage Laravel date you can use a beautiful package named Carbon that resolve your problem with `Carbon::parse("data");`

here you can fine documentation.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/
And here the api documentation for Laravel:

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Carbon.html

Comment: Thanks, carbon helps but isn't perfect. I used: `$birthday = Carbon::parse($birthday);`, now i can convert 1.1.2017 but still not 1.1.17.. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As LorenzoBerti mentioned you can use carbon to parse your date:

```
$birthday = Carbon::parse($birthday)->format('d.m.y');
```

Notice the `format()` method, this should give you the format that you need.

Comment: The output format isn't the problem. The Problem is, that `Carbon::parse(1.1.17)` doesn't return 2017-01-01 but returns the current day. `Carbon::parse(1.1.2017)` works.